# Train a multi-input CNN with image data generators

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, imagedatagenerator

I have got a dataset of images which is organized as follows:

-dir_path Folder:
---train-testa SubFolder:
-------train (contains 6 subfolders (class 1 to 6) each contain image samples)
-------val (contains 6 subfolders (class 1 to 6) each contain image samples)
---train-testb SubFolder:
-------train (contains 6 subfolders (class 1 to 6) each contain image samples)
-------val (contains 6 subfolders (class 1 to 6) each contain image samples)
---train-testc SubFolder:
-------train (contains 6 subfolders (class 1 to 6) each contain image samples)
-------val (contains 6 subfolders (class 1 to 6) each contain image samples)

I want to train a CNN with 3 images as inputs at a time. For example,
\dir_path\train-testa\train\class3\sample05.png,
\dir_path\train-testb\train\class3\sample05.png,
\dir_path\train-testc\train\class3\sample05.png

would be an concatenated input to the CNN for training. validation input would be the same but the samples are just drawn from val subfolders.

I used ImageDataGenerators as follows:

```
image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255)

def generate_generator_multiple(generator,dir1, dir2, dir3, batch_size, img_height,img_width):
    genX1 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir1,
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'categorical',
                                          batch_size = batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          seed=7)

    genX2 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir2,
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'categorical',
                                          batch_size = batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          seed=7)
    genX3 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir2,
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'categorical',
                                          batch_size = batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          seed=7)
    while True:
            X1i = genX1.next()
            X2i = genX2.next()
            X3i = genX3.next()
            yield [X1i[0], X2i[0], X3i[0]], X2i[1]  #Yield images and their mutual label


train_generator=generate_generator_multiple(generator=image_generator,
                                           dir1=dir_path + "\\train-testa" + "\\train",
                                           dir2=dir_path + "\\train-testb" + "\\train",
                                           dir3=dir_path + "\\train-testc" + "\\train",
                                           batch_size=30,
                                           img_height=217,
                                           img_width=217)
test_generator=generate_generator_multiple(generator=image_generator,
                                           dir1=dir_path + "\\train-testa" + "\\val",
                                           dir2=dir_path + "\\train-testb" + "\\val",
                                           dir3=dir_path + "\\train-testc" + "\\val",
                                           batch_size=30,
                                           img_height=217,
                                           img_width=217)
```

In the above function, I merged the generators from each of train-testa, b and c. I used the following CNN Model:

```
def CNNModel(input_shape): 
    
    X_input1 = Input(input_shape)
    X_input2 = Input(input_shape)
    X_input3 = Input(input_shape)

    X = layers.concatenate([X_input1, X_input2, X_input3])
    
    X = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides = (1, 1), name = 'conv1')(X)
    X = Activation('LeakyReLU')(X)
    X = Dropout(.25)(X)
    X = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='max_pool1')(X) 
    
    X = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides = (1, 1), name = 'conv2')(X)
    X = Activation('LeakyReLU')(X)
    X = Dropout(.3)(X)
    X = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='max_pool2')(X) 
    
    X = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides = (1, 1), name = 'conv3')(X)
    X = Activation('LeakyReLU')(X)
    X = Dropout(.3)(X)
    
    X = Flatten()(X)
    
    X = Dense(64, activation='LeakyReLU', name='fc1')(X)
    X = Dropout(.4)(X)
    
    X = Dense(6, activation='softmax', name='fc2')(X)
    
    return model
```

Finally, I trained the model with this code:

```
CNN_Model = CNNModel((217, 217, 3));

CNN_Model.compile(optimizer = "adam",loss = "categorical_crossentropy",metrics = ["accuracy"])

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=50, verbose=1, restore_best_weights=True)

his = CNN_Model.fit(train_generator, epochs=200, validation_data=test_generator, callbacks=[callback], use_multiprocessing=False)
```

Now I have some issues:
1- Is the logic (concept) of my code correct for the problem?
2- Training process is too slow. My total images for training is 630 files and it has been near 3 hours and still I haven't been able to see the final results. The number of epochs might be too large but I have run the same code for single input image and it took only a few minutes.This is what I get during run:
"
device:GPU:0 with 1654 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
Epoch 1/200
21527/Unknown - 10706s 497ms/step - loss: 0.3556 - accuracy: 0.9668"

And its training accuracy, although very slowly, is still increasing. It's very likely that it's being overfitted. As you can observe, I can see neither of how many steps are left nor the validation accuracy.
Since I need to train larger datasets, is there a way to improve the speed?
I would be grateful if you could share me your suggestions.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ImageDataGenerator, it's very slow and already deprecated. Use `image_dataset_from_directory` instead. Here are more info: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory

In this case you can use 3 times image_dataset_from_directory to create 3 datasets, and then you can concatenate them into one using something like `tf.data.Dataset.zip((a, b, c))`. You may need to map then, you can do that using `dataset.map(...)`.

You can also apply prefetch, and cache it to speed up. Here is the info: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance